# CDC Clean Job Is not Deleting Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, cdc

In my CDC table. I have,

```
__$start_lsn         __$end_lsn        __$seqval     __$operation   __$update_mask
0x0000004600002EF40004  NULL    0x0000004600002EF40003  3             0x08
0x0000004600002EF40004  NULL    0x0000004600002EF40003  4             0x08
```

In my `msdb.dbo.cdc_jobs`

```
database_id job_type job_id maxtrans    maxscans    continuous  pollinginterval retention   threshold
9           capture   xxx        500     10           1              5              0        0
9           cleanup   xx          0      0             0             0             4320   5000
```

`select sys.Fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(0x0000004600002EF40004)` returns
`2023-04-08 11:23:25.467`

Retention is 3 days. Cleanup agent job is running `sys.sp_MScdc_cleanup_job` daily. Why there are still rows in my CDC table as I am thinking after 3 days retention these old rows should be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was SQL Server 2017 issue. After installing the cumulative update it start deleting.

[CDC capture sys.sp_MScdc_capture_job throwing maximum nesting level error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76169656/cdc-capture-sys-sp-mscdc-capture-job-throwing-maximum-nesting-level-error)