# CDC capture sys.sp_MScdc_capture_job throwing maximum nesting level error

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

I have enabled CDC that enabled capture and cleanup job in SQL Server agent. When I am seeing the logs of the job I am seeing the below error,

[image]

The procedure `sys.sp_MScdc_capture_job` is throwing `maximum stored procedure nesting level exceed`. I have checked all documentation and could not found why this error happening.

Comment: have you modified something? it seems like you have some problematic trigger that doesn't jump out properly

Comment: @siggemannen it was SQL Server 2017 issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you working with SQL Server 2017 then you must install [Cumulative Update 4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb4073684-fix-change-data-capture-does-not-work-in-sql-server-2017-dc398e7e-d5db-f153-c820-be58e93d4d4b) for SQL Server 2017.